# Discord bot crashes after starting

Tags: python, discord, dotenv, replicate

i tried to use this code and everythink looks quite cool but everytime im gettin an big error after second from starting

```
from discord import Intents
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import replicate

os.environ["DISCORD_TOKEN"] = "TOKEN"

load_dotenv()



intents = Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix="!",
    description="Runs models on Replicate!",
    intents=intents,
)


@bot.command(aliases=["sd"])
async def stable_diffusion(ctx, *, prompt):
    """Generate an image from a text prompt using the stable-diffusion model"""
    msg = await ctx.send(f"“{prompt}”\n> Generating...")

    model = replicate.models.get("stability-ai/stable-diffusion")
    image = model.predict(prompt=prompt)[0]

    await msg.edit(content=f"“{prompt}”\n{image}")


bot.run(os.environ["DISCORD_TOKEN"])
```

error message

```
\[2022-11-17 20:33:21\] \[INFO    \] discord.client: logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bot.py", line 34, in \<module\>
bot.run(os.environ\["DISCORD_TOKEN"\])
File "C:\\Users\\Roman\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\discord\\client.py", line 828, in run
asyncio.run(runner())
File "C:\\Users\\Roman\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\asyncio\\runners.py", line 43, in run
return loop.run_until_complete(main)
File "C:\\Users\\Roman\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\asyncio\\base_events.py", line 608, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
File "C:\\Users\\Roman\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\discord\\client.py", line 817, in runner
await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
File "C:\\Users\\Roman\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\discord\\client.py", line 746, in start
await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
File "C:\\Users\\Roman\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\discord\\client.py", line 672, in connect
raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.
Exception ignored in: \<function \_ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001CBA8AA73A0\>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\Roman\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\asyncio\\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
self.close()
File "C:\\Users\\Roman\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\asyncio\\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
self.\_loop.call_soon(self.\_call_connection_lost, None)
File "C:\\Users\\Roman\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\asyncio\\base_events.py", line 711, in call_soon
self.\_check_closed()
File "C:\\Users\\Roman\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\asyncio\\base_events.py", line 504, in \_check_closed
raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty straightforward - " Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead."  `intents.message_content = True` ... this is a privileged intent

Comment: your secret token has leaked in the question, you should consider generating a new one and avoid posting it on SO.